# Authorise all users of a client application to access Signalr Hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I'm attempting to host a SignalR Hub that will allow real-time communication between a bus driver on an Android tablet and their dispatcher who uses a Windows application. These applications will only see controlled release, and so I can assume that if someone is using either the Android app or the Windows one they are who they claim to be. With this in mind, how can I authenticate these users? I don't want to worry about individual logons, I just want to prevent the Hub from being accessed by random people.

A solution that comes to mind is to include a secret token in the distribution of the apps. Is this good practice (if "good practice" questions are out of scope for this SO site let me know)? If so, how should it be done? Include the token in the source code, include it as an asset, etc?

Thank you very much for any help!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You can't 100% prevent your hub from being accessed outside your app, but you can restrict it.

a standard way to restrict accessing to only your app is to use `OpenID connect` and `OAuth`,

for your needs you may want to use `Client Credentials Grant` flow were you grant access to a client (in this case the app) by exchanging `ClientId` and/or `ClientSecret` with an `AccessToken`

this flow helps authenticate your app, but keep in mind if someone were to obtain the `ClientSecret` he can still be authenticated to use your signalr apis

also you may want to take a look at `IdentityServer` a great lib for c# to handle `OAuth and openID` for you

Answer (score 1):

Other option would be client certificates given to each user that they then use to sign their SignalR communications. Hub would then simply ignore messages that don't contain valid signature.

Of course all security concerns regarding private keys transfer/storing would be in place.